# Implementing method with another method

Tags: java, string, methods

I need help with my code which is made up of two methods. I want to use my method "obify" with "normalizeText". The goal is to put OB in before every vowel i the text that user inputs.  I know that when I put this:

```
    String c =  b.replaceAll("(?i)([aeiou])", "OB$1");

    System.out.println(c);
```

inside normalizeTest method, it works. But I want to make a method called obify() that does this without putting it inside normalizeText().

This is the code that I am trying to work with.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Text {
public static void main( String[] args){

  normalizeText();
  obify();


  }
static void normalizeText(){
String a;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.print("Write your String");
a = scan.nextLine();



System.out.print("String is: " + a);



a = a.replaceAll("\\W", "");


 a = a.toUpperCase();



 String b = a.replaceAll("\\s", "");

      /* then I just return the text that the user input
      but now without the spaces or punctuations. The text will also
     be in all caps
      */
       System.out.println("\n output String is:" + b);

   /*
 String c =  b.replaceAll("(?i)([aeiou])", "OB$1");
 System.out.println(c);
    */


}

static void obify(){

String c =  b.replaceAll("(?i)([aeiou])", "OB$1");
System.out.println(c);

}


    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: I dont understand what's the problem?

Comment: Looks like you have scoping issues

Comment: change return type of normalizeText() function to String and add result to the parameter of obify function : `static String normalizeText()` , `static void obify(String b)`

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to use some return types on that. Here's an example of what the code could look like:

```
public static void main( String[] args){

  String textToDoStuffTo = "Change this text";  

  //you can do it like this
  textToDoStuffTo = normalizeText(textToDoStuffTo);
  textToDoStuffTo  = obify(textToDoStuffTo);

  //or you can combine them like this
  normalizeText(obify(textToDoStuffTo));

}

static String normalizeText(String text){
    //changes the text
    return text;
}

static String obify(String text){
    //changes the text
    return text;
}
```